# What condition should I use to make my code work with a local variable?

Tags: c++, global, local

So this code gives us the prime numbers. But it only works if int `a[1499]` is a global variable because if an array is global it automatically initializes all the members to `0`. How can I change the condition of the `for`-loop so that I can make `a[1499]` a local variable and move it to function `main`?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int a[1499];

int main()
{
    int PrimeCounter = 0;
    int PrimeNumberNeeded = 1500;
    bool Isprime;
    int TestNumber = 2;

    a[0]=2;
    while (PrimeCounter != PrimeNumberNeeded)
    {
        Isprime = true;

        for(int x=0; a[x]!= 0; x++)
        {
            if(TestNumber%a[x] == 0)
            {
                Isprime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (Isprime)
        {
            a[PrimeCounter] = TestNumber;
            PrimeCounter++;
        }
        TestNumber++;
    }
    // end of while
    if (PrimeCounter == PrimeNumberNeeded)
    {
        cout << "Prime counter is: " << PrimeCounter << "\nTest number is: "<< a[1499]<< endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int a[1499] = {0};` inside `main()` will also initialize all the elements to zero...

Answer (score 1):

Move the definition of `a` inside the function and give it an initializer:

```
int a[1499] = {0};
```

This explicitly initializes the first element to 0, and implicitly initializes the rest to 0 as well.

Comment: If I use an online c++ compiler it works but on code::blocks it doesn't work. It's not giving any error, it just sits there doing nothing.

Comment: The fact you're trying to put 1,500 numbers into 1,499 boxes probably isn't helping matters.

Comment: Thank you! It works now. Although I don't get it why it works when  use it as a global.

Comment: That's undefined behavior for you. But it's probably because it's not trampling all over your stack when it's global, or over any other global data when it's the only global.

Comment: Great explanation! it's first time I hear about UB. I'll look more into it. Thanks again!